# How to get innerHTML of div onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the following code, how to get the text inside `div` on the `onClick` event?

```
import React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";

class TestTag extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div onClick={() => console.log(this.innerHTML)}> Hello world </div>;
  }
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<TestTag />);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the `event` to your `onClick` handler and get the innterHTML/innerText,

```html
<div onClick={(e) => console.log(e.target.innerHTML)}> Hello world </div>;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how committed you are to using a "this", but you can easily get the text this way:

```
    import React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";

class TestTag extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div id = "maindiv" onClick={() => console.log(document.getElementById("maindiv").innerHTML)}> Hello world </div>;
  }
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<TestTag />);
```